# How to organize connection only once (node.js +express+ socket.io)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have many functions where I need use socket.io but I want organize connection only once. Users are connected like this:

```
exports.sendInvite = function(io) {
  let usersMap = new Map;
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.info(`client connected socketId = ${socket.id}`);
    console.log("session_id: " + socket.request.session.session_id);
    usersMap.set(socket.request.session.session_id, socket.id);
    console.log("Map size: " + usersMap.size);

    //some actions....
    //and disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      usersMap.delete(socket.request.session.session_id);
      console.log('user disconnected');
      console.log("Map size: " + usersMap.size);     
    });
  }); 
}
```

But I have another functions where I need use socket.io. How can I connect users only once and use their `socket.id` many times in other functions. Please, help me.